# Run multiple hive query from pyspark on the same session

Tags: python-3.x, hive, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run a Hive query with pyspark. I am using Hortonworks so I need to use the [Hive WarehouseConnector](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehousesession_api_operations.html).

Running one or even multiple queries is easy and works. My problem is that I want to issue `set` commands before. For instance to set the dag name in tez ui: `set hive.query.name=something relevant` or to set up some memory configuration `set hive.tez.container.size = 8192`. For these statements to take effect, they need to run on the same session than the main query and that's my issue.

I tried 2 ways:

The first one was to generate a new hive session **for each query**, with a properly setup url eg.:

```
url='jdbc:hive2://hiveserver:10000/default?hive.query.name=relevant'
builder = HiveWarehouseSession.session(self.spark)
builder.hs2url(url)
hive = builder.build()
hive.execute("select * from whatever")
```

It works well for the first query, but the same url is reused for the next one (even if I try to manually delete `builder` and `hive`), so does not work.

The second way is to set `spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession=true` globally in the spark thrift server. This does seem to work, but I find it a shame to limit the global spark thrift server for the benefit of one application only.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for? Maybe there could be a way to pin a query to one executor, so hopefully one session?

Answer (score 0):

this has been a big peeve of mine...still is actually.

The solution that resolved this issue for me was putting all the queries in a query file, where each query would be separated by a semicolon. Then I run the query using beeline from within a python script.

Unfortunately, it does not work with queries that return results...only suitable for set, overwrite, insert kind of queries.

In case you might have discovered a more efficient way to do this, please do share.